# React: setting state of button to disabled makes it impossible to tick checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application that consists of three components:

1. A HTML table
2. a table row that contains a checkbox
3. A button

I want the button to be disabled if none of the checkboxes are ticked. It should be enabled if one or more of the checkboxes are ticked.

I am using a javascript Set to keep track of any ticked checkboxes.

EDIT:  You can see a demo here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w2rlywxzol

The table row has the following code:

```
class EventRowAdmin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    console.log('target checked' + target.checked);
    this.setState({
      isChecked: target.checked
    });
    this.props.manageCheckboxes(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr id={this.props.id}>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.handleChange} className="remove-event"/></td>
        <td>{this.props.date}</td>
        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.location}</td>
        <td>{this.props.ticketLink}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

The table contains this code to manage the checkboxes:

```
class EventsTableAdmin extends Component {

  ...

  componentWillMount() {
    this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
  }
  manageCheckboxes(id) {
    console.log('id is:' + id);
    if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(id)) {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(id);
    } else {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.add(id);
    }

    if(this.selectedCheckboxes.size > 0) {
      this.setState({ deleteButtonDisabled: false});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ deleteButtonDisabled: true});
    }
  }

  makeEventsTable() {
    const events = this.props.data;
    const eventsRows = events.map((event, i) => {
      let key = `event-${Date.now()}-${i}`;
      let id = i;
      return (
        <EventRowAdmin manageCheckboxes={this.manageCheckboxes} key={key} id={id} date={event.date} name={event.name} location={event.location} ticketLink={event.ticketLink} />
      );
    });
    return eventsRows;
  }

  render() {
    <ButtonDeleteEvents isDisabled={this.state.deleteButtonDisabled} handleDeleteEvents={this.handleDeleteEvents} />
    <table className="table table-events table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr><th></th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Ticket Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.makeEventsTable() }
    </tbody>
  </table>

}
```

The button has this code:

```
class ButtonDeleteEvents extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button disabled={this.props.isDisabled} onClick={this.props.handleDeleteEvents} className="btn secondary">Delete Selected Events</button>
    )
  }

}
```

The key code is the following in the EventsTableAdmin component:

```
if(this.selectedCheckboxes.size > 0) {
  this.setState({ deleteButtonDisabled: false});
}
else {
  this.setState({ deleteButtonDisabled: true});
}
```

If I remove this code I can tick the checkboxes.  But if the code is there its not possible to tick the checkboxes.

How can this be occurring since there is no dependency that I can see between the state of deleteButtonDisabled and the state of the checkboxes?

Comment: Obviously, putting `disabled` on a `button` won't have any effect on `input type="checkbox"` elements somewhere near it. :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Demo here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/w2rlywxzol

Comment: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. That's why I made a point of referring you to how to put your example **in** the question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/

Comment: Is your complete row disabled or just the checkboxes ? also inspect element to see if the button or any other element is overlapping, maybe!

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is you were storing the whole array in `this` variable store it in `state` variable because updating this not re-render component but if you store it in state and update using `this.setState()` the component will get renders and you can see update UI.

**Problem 2**: your `checked` in `state` is not per row or as per id. its is signle variable used for all rows.

Have look problem resolved: https://codesandbox.io/s/6wnxj77qjn

Answer (score 0):

When you change the state of the EventsTableAdmin on line 67, all components bound to that Component will be forced to re-render. So on the constructor of your `EventRowAdmin` you have set your `isChecked` value to false therefore, the checkbox state will be reset to false every time the component re-renders.